# How to bind key value pair to dropdown in MVC4 Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have country table "tblCountry", Where there is 2 columns country name, Country ID, I want to display country name but store country id in rest of the tables. Please tell me the approach  from creating models to view, I am using database first approach.

```
public partial class tblRFATCountry
{
    public long CountryID { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

This is my model where i tried to add a dictionary.

```
public partial class tblRFATCountry
{
    public long CountryID { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public dictionary<string, long> countryDic = new dictionary<string, long>();
}
```

I want to do something like that so that i can display name but store value. Please suggest

Comment: Can you share the code you have tried for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to do something like :

```
@{

    Dictionary<long, string> dictionaryCountry = new Dictionary<long, string>()
    {
      {1, "Item1"},
      {2, "Item2"},
      {3, "Item3"},
      {4, "Item4"},
    };



     SelectList countryList= new SelectList(
            dictionaryCountry.Select(x => new { Value = x.Key, Text = x.Value }),
            "Value",
            "Text"
        );

}

@Html.DropDownList("DDLCounry", countryList)
```

you can refer [here](http://library.logicsistemi.it/en/net/51-asp-net-mvc-c-dictionary-to-dropdownlist) for more [details](http://library.logicsistemi.it/en/net/51-asp-net-mvc-c-dictionary-to-dropdownlist)

Comment: How do you ever retrieve the value from the currently selected item in your controller?

Comment: @JancodeVries it will be posted back as key value pair in the request

Answer (score 4):

The dropdown list can be implemented as follows

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCountryId, new SelectList(Model.Countries, "CountryID", "Country"), "Please select a country")
```

The ViewModel would then need the following properties

```
public long SelectedCountryId {get; set;}
public List<tblRFATCountry> Countries {get; set;}
```

Comment: Thanks for you r valuable answer, so table would change if I change view model?

Comment: What do you mean the table will chnage if you chnage the viewModel. when positing the view back, the viewModel will contain the selected id from the drop down in the `SelectedCountryId` field.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of an utility class you can do something like this

**C# Utility Class**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace YourNameSpace.Domain.Utilities
{
    public static class DropDownList<T>
    {
        public static SelectList LoadItems(IList<T> collection, string value, string text)
        {
            return new SelectList(collection, value, text);
        }
    }

}
```

**Controller**

```
ViewBag.CountryList = Domain.Utilities.DropDownList<tblRFATCountry>.LoadItems(YourRepository.Countries.ToList(), 
"CityID", "CityName");
```

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CountryList, "--Select--", new { @class = "select" })
```

Comment: Thanks, Where should i put this utility class. I am new to this stuff, Thanks again.

Comment: I would put this Utility namespace in my Domain assembly, but is up to you, you could put that in a separated utilities assembly, for future reuse

Comment: Hi I tried but I am not getting anything in "ViewBag.CountryList" Enumerator yield no result. Please help

Comment: Hi have tried this 
 ViewBag.CountryList =
               RFATUtility.DropDownList<tblRFATCountry>.LoadItems(dbpm.tblRFATCountries.ToList(), "CountryID", "CountryName");

DBPM is dbcontext class.